# Xcode 4.6.2: Variable Doesn't Show Up In Outlets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, variables, uiwebview

I want to make a second UIWebView in a second View Controller on my Storyboard.

This is my SecondViewController.h:

```
@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *Cafeteria;
}

@end
```

However, when I try to connect the Variable "Cafeteria" to the UIWebView, the variable does not appear in the Outputs:

http://i.imgur.com/IXFfirY.png

In the first view controller, I successfully connected the variable but on the second it simply doesn't show up.

Help!

Comment: What class is the owner of your secondViewController in xib?

Comment: I should've clarified, I am using Storyboard, not xib.

Answer (score 3):

The awnser is easy as you thought. Just select the `ViewController` and click on the connections inspector like here:

[image]

The next step is to connect the `outlet`! Do it like this:

[image]

However, if the `outlet` doesn't appear on the inspector that make shure you connected the right `header` file to the `ViewController`. Select the controller and change the class name to the name of your `header` file.

[image]

Good luck.
Noah

Comment: Thank you so much!
My error was that my class wasn't the same as the ThirdViewController.h.. 

Thanks!!

Comment: @LukasOppenheimer Don't forget to accept the awnser with a "tick" ;)